# What is the latest version of RetroFit before 2.0?

Tags: retrofit

Does it stop at 1.9.0 or is there a 1.9.1+?

I am running into some null-binding issues and was hoping to upgrade this dependency without much refactoring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Please see their github for more info

https://github.com/square/retrofit/tags?before=parent-1.9.0